# How to move a sprite from point A to B using move modifier in andengin?

Tags: android, andengine

I am new to game development.am using and-engine to develop the game.am create sprite (Example:- arrow to hit the enemy) when user touch the screen use scene touch listener.Am use move modifier to move arrow.But the arrow is not display in the screen.When i touch the screen in log-cat shows

**Log Cat Error**

```
10-29 18:36:41.913: V/AndEngine(25704): org.andengine.input.touch.TouchEvent$TouchEventPool<TouchEvent> was exhausted, with 0 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.

10-29 18:36:41.913: V/AndEngine(25704): org.andengine.util.adt.pool.PoolUpdateHandler$1<TouchEventRunnablePoolItem> was exhausted, with 0 item not yet recycled. Allocated 1 more.
```

**Code**

```
private void shootProjectile(final float pX, final float pY) {

        int offX = (int) (pX - player.getX());
        int offY = (int) (pY - player.getY());
        if (offX <= 0)
            return;

        final Sprite projectile;
        // position the projectile on the player
        projectile = new Sprite(player.getX(), player.getY(),
                arrow.deepCopy(),mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        mainScene.attachChild(projectile);

        int realX = (int) (camera.getWidth() + projectile.getWidth() / 2.0f);
        float ratio = (float) offY / (float) offX;
        int realY = (int) ((realX * ratio) + projectile.getY());

        int offRealX = (int) (realX - projectile.getX());
        int offRealY = (int) (realY - projectile.getY());
        float length = (float) Math.sqrt((offRealX * offRealX) + (offRealY * offRealY));
        float velocity = 480.0f / 1.0f; // 480 pixels / 1 sec
        float realMoveDuration = length / velocity;

        // defining a move modifier from the projectile's position to the
        // calculated one
        MoveModifier mod = new MoveModifier(realMoveDuration,projectile.getX(), realX, projectile.getY(), realY);
        projectile.registerEntityModifier(mod);

        /*projectile.registerEntityModifier(modifier);

        PhysicsHandler handler = new PhysicsHandler(projectile);

        projectile.registerUpdateHandler(handler);

        handler.setVelocity(realX,realY);*/

        projectilesToBeAdded.add(projectile);
        // plays a shooting sound
    }
```

from the above code move the arrow sprite to the direction Wherever touch the screen.But am not able to display the arrow sprite.Can any one know please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things that will be helpful:

1. Those error messages are warning level messages, not errors. They are the correct operation of andengine. When there are no touches in the touch pool, it issues a warning when a new one is created. After some touches are in the pool, they get recycled, so the message only crops up when the number of touches required exceeds the number in the pool. Summary: Don't worry about this.
2. When you create your sprite, I see something kinda odd for the TextureRegion argument "Arrow.deepCopy()". My guess is that that method does not return a valid TextureRegion, and so your arrow is not displayed. Since any number of sprites can use the same textureRegion, I recommend just using a standard reference to your arrow texture.

The scope of the problem will be one of two things: there is no texture, or the arrow is being placed off screen. So first place the sprite where you know it will be seen, with no modifier. If you see it your texture is good. 
If the texture is good, then the position is bad in your modifier, so check your maths again and try again.